# Add extra methods at compile time according to some enum value

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Imagine I have the following class:

```
class Extra final
{
public:

    void Method1() const {std::cout << "Method 1" << std::endl;}
    void Method2() const {std::cout << "Method 2" << std::endl;}
};
```

I created, for some class `T`, a class template that can enable/disable methods using `Extra` at compile time according to different scenarios (listed in an enum):

```
enum class Scenario
{
    None, // No extra.
    One,  // Only Method1 allowed.
    Two,  // Only Method2 allowed.
    Both  // Both Method1 and Method2 allowed.
};
```

The class template looks as follow:

```
template<typename T, Scenario R>
class ExtraAdder : public T
{
};

template<typename T>
class ExtraAdder<T, Scenario::One> : public T
{
public:

    void Method1Extra() const {m_extra.Method1();}

private:

    Extra m_extra;
};

template<typename T>
class ExtraAdder<T, Scenario::Two> : public T
{
public:

    void Method2Extra() const {m_extra.Method2();}

private:

    Extra m_extra;
};

template<typename T>
class ExtraAdder<T, Scenario::Both> : public T
{
public:

    void Method1Extra() const {m_extra.Method1();}
    void Method2Extra() const {m_extra.Method2();}

private:

    Extra m_extra;
};
```

It can be used as follow:

```
class Base
{
public:

    virtual ~Base() = default;
    void BaseMethod() const {std::cout << "Base method" << std::endl;}

    // Some other stuff...
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << "Scenario: None" << std::endl;
    ExtraAdder<Base, Scenario::None> none;
    none.BaseMethod();
    //none.Method1Extra();   // Does not compile.
    //none.Method2Extra();   // Does not compile.

    std::cout << std::endl << "Scenario: One" << std::endl;
    ExtraAdder<Base, Scenario::One> one;
    one.BaseMethod();
    one.Method1Extra();
    //one.Method2Extra();    // Does not compile.

    std::cout << std::endl << "Scenario: Two" << std::endl;
    ExtraAdder<Base, Scenario::Two> two;
    two.BaseMethod();
    //two.Method1Extra();    // Does not compile.
    two.Method2Extra();

    std::cout << std::endl << "Scenario: Both" << std::endl;
    ExtraAdder<Base, Scenario::Both> both;
    both.BaseMethod();
    both.Method1Extra();
    both.Method2Extra();

    return 0;
}
```

The point is that by changing the template parameter `Scenario`, I can only have access to some method(s) of the wrapped `m_extra` member, which is exactly what I want. However, as you can see, the different specializations are very verbose (and have some duplication).

**Question**: Is there a way to produce the exact same template specializations, but in a less verbose way, with limited or no duplication?

The closest I have found to solve this is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289397/add-method-to-class-by-template-parameter) (using `std::enable_if`), but I have not been able to adapt it to my case.

I am using g++ with the C++17 standard.

Comment: Is there no common state shared between added methods (i.e. is `class Extra` empty in your actual code)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you can put the `enable_if` into the template instead of the return type declaration. I personally find this a bit more readable, and it has the advantage that you can use return type deduction.

```
template<typename T, Scenario R>
class ExtraAdder : public T {
    Extra m_extra;
public:
    template<
        Scenario S = R, 
        typename = std::enable_if_t<(S == Scenario::One || S == Scenario::Both)>
    >
    void Method1Extra() const {
        m_extra.Method1();
    }

    
    template<
        Scenario S = R, 
        typename = std::enable_if_t<(S == Scenario::Two || S == Scenario::Both)>
    >
    decltype(auto) Method2Extra() const {
       return m_extra.Method2();
    }

};
```

Live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/xfEcGP).

A common pitfall of using `enable_if` with member functions is that it only works if substitution of a template argument is ill-formed. Therefore we need to add that extra template parameter `Scenario S = R` (or the `bool` in the other answer) in order to defer the substitution to the point where the method is being used. Otherwise there wouldn't be such a substitution resulting in a hard error. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function) for a more in-depth discussion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enable_if` but you also need to make the member functions template functions so the checks can be dependent on something:

```cpp
template<typename T, Scenario R>
class ExtraAdder : public T {
    Extra m_extra;
public:
    template<bool B = true>
    std::enable_if_t<B && (R == Scenario::One || R == Scenario::Both)>
    Method1Extra() const {
        m_extra.Method1();
    }

    template<bool B = true>
    std::enable_if_t<B && (R == Scenario::Two || R == Scenario::Both)>
    Method2Extra() const {
        m_extra.Method2();
    }
};
```

If you don't need to SFINAE on whether those methods exist, you can simply `static_assert`:

```cpp
template<typename T, Scenario R>
class ExtraAdder : public T {
    Extra m_extra;
public:
    void Method1Extra() const {
        static_assert(R == Scenario::One || R == Scenario::Both);
        m_extra.Method1();
    }

    void Method2Extra() const {
        static_assert(R == Scenario::Two || R == Scenario::Both);
        m_extra.Method2();
    }
};
```

Comment: or directly `template <Scenario S = R> std::enable_if_t<(S == Scenario::One) || (S == Scenario::Both)>`, avoiding `B`.